# Align items in navigation bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Ciao! I have a navigation-bar at the top of a website with only two elements: a menu-icon and a brand-logo (Eiffeltower). The idea is to place the Eiffeltower image in the center of the nav-bar and the menu-icon at the very left side (in the withe area) of the nav-bar but I have some troubles with placing this correctly in CSS.

`text-align: center` seems not to work so I set up some `padding` commands, but I don't think this is a nice solution. And I can't figure out how to place the `fa fa-bar` to the left. I need some help! Can you take a look?

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/iJup/pen/jbrwRW?editors=100)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>JFP</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/app.js"></script>
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  
  <style>
    .nav {
     list-style:none;
     margin:0 8%;
     padding:0;
     position:relative;
     text-align:center;
     background: rgb(51,51,51);
     color:rgb(51,51,51);
     font-size:140%;
     padding:0px 10px;
     font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 120px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 120px;
    }
    .nav li {
     position:relative;
     z-index:2;
     display:inline-block;
     vertical-align:bottom;
     text-transform:uppercase;
    }
      
    .nav a, .nav span {
     display:block;
     color:#fff;
     text-decoration:none;
     margin:0 20px;
    padding-right: 80px;
    }
      
    .nav a:visited{
      color:rgb(51,51,51)
    }
      
    .nav:after{
     content:"";
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     bottom:50%;
     right:0;
     left:0;
     background: rgb(51,51,51);
    }
      
    .nav span{
     width:186px;
     height:77px;
     background:rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
     font-size:77px; 
     overflow:hidden;
    }
      
    .nav #brand {
      height: 160px;
      width: 80px;
      position: absolute;
    }
    
    .nav #fafa {
      font-size: 30px;
      color: rgb(42, 186, 214);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav center">
    <li><i id="fafa" class="fa fa-bars"></i></li>
    <li class="logo"><span><img id="brand" alt="Brand" src="https://photos-3.dropbox.com/t/2/AACJhIINsVBRwEqcMxgWNfqZu5OrjdJRMjG46W7GeV_ttw/12/5046553/jpeg/32x32/1/_/1/2/Eiffeltoren-logo.jpg/EOzL4wMYgEUgASgB/M6Hyu4cmSoxBTnl8a18nWaMYKaQpYmF2AznL32KgdT0?size=1024x768&size_mode=2"></span></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `float: left` on the `li` containing the menu icon like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/322/

```
<ul class="nav center">
    <li class="menubar"><i id="fafa" class="fa fa-bars"></i></li>
    <li class="logo"><span><img id="brand" alt="Brand" src="https://photos-3.dropbox.com/t/2/AACJhIINsVBRwEqcMxgWNfqZu5OrjdJRMjG46W7GeV_ttw/12/5046553/jpeg/32x32/1/_/1/2/Eiffeltoren-logo.jpg/EOzL4wMYgEUgASgB/M6Hyu4cmSoxBTnl8a18nWaMYKaQpYmF2AznL32KgdT0?size=1024x768&size_mode=2"/></span></li>
</ul>
.nav .menubar {
    float: left;
}
```

UPDATED: with menu in the white area: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/325/

```
margin-left: -55px;
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to get the menu-icon to the left out of the grey area into the white area?

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways you can go. Either use the `float` property, like that:

```
float: left;
```

or, you can set `position: absolute;` and then use the `left` property like this:

```
left: 10px;
```

You can find more about how to horizontally align elements in CSS from [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp) link.

Comment: Is there a possibility to get the menu-icon to the left out of the grey area into the white area?

Comment: You could change your `.nav #fafa` to something like:    `.nav #fafa {
      font-size: 30px;
      color: rgb(42, 186, 214);
      position: absolute;
      left: -30px;
    }`